# SP 2010: hide/disable column in edit form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I've got a list (based on custom list) with several custom columns. There is one column, that I want to protect from changes by the user (it will be set/changed by webservice call and should not be changed in UI).

**How can I hide/disable this column in the new and edit forms**, when customizing with InfoPath oder SharePoint Designer aren't options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to show this field in the Display Form? 
If not you should mark your field as hidden in the content type properties it won't be shown in the forms (in InfoPath too).

If you want to show it on the Display form only read  [this post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/05/how-to-hide-column-of-sharepoint-list.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Forms Designer tool](http://spform.com). It provides easy-to-use browser interface to design forms, hide or disable fields. With its rich javascript framework you can make more complex logic, e.g fill some fields' value based on other fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by using custom edit forms and override the CreateChildControls method as described in this article :
http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/10/read-only-fields-in-some-lists-for-some.html

Comment: i have implemented custom edit forms to achieve this functionality in my project and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the columns using the [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) utility.  All you have to do is navigate the tree structure of your SharePoint server [Web Application -> Site Collection -> Site -> List -> Fields] and then edit the ShowInXXXForm property in the right menu and click save.  I found the solution on this detailed [blog entry](http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/11/hide-columns-in-sharepoint-new-edit-and.html).